# sorting array based on child array[0] (unix) value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need an array sorted by **Unix** timestamp values. I attempted to use both `ksort` and `krsort` before realising that occasionally the timestamp values might be the same (and you cannot have duplicate keys in arrays).

Here's an example array I may be faced with:

```
$array = array(
    [
        "unix"      => 1556547761, // notice the two duplicate unix values
        "random"    => 4
    ],
    [
        "unix"      => 1556547761,
        "random"    => 2
    ],
    [
        "unix"      => 1556547769,
        "random"    => 5
    ],
    [
        "unix"      => 1556547765, // this should be in the 3rd position
        "random"    => 9
    ]
);
```

So what I'm trying to do is sort them all based on each child arrays `unix` value, however I cannot figure out how to do so. I have tried countless insane ways (including all other `sort` functions and many, many `for` loops) to figure it out - but to no avail.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[array_multisort()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)** — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays
>
> **[array_columns()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)** — Return the values from a single column in the input array

You can use `array_multisort()` and `array_column()`, then provide your desired sort order (`SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC`).

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, "unix"), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

**Explanation:**

In `array_multisort()`, arrays are sorted by the first array given. You can see we are using `array_column($array, "unix")`, which means that the second parameter is the order of sorting (ascending or descending) and the third parameter is the original array.

This is the result of `array_column($array, "unix")`:

```
Array(
    [0] => 1556547761
    [1] => 1556547761
    [2] => 1556547765
    [3] => 1556547769
)
```

Comment: Let me give it a shot! :)

Comment: Any chance you can explain how this works a bit better? It's very compact and works, however it lacks explanation.

Comment: @GROVER. I have mentioned the explanation in the solution, hope you will understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [usort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which sort your array by given function

Define function as:

```
function cmpByUnix($a, $b) {
    return $a["unix"] - $b["unix"];
}
```

And use with: `usort($array, "cmpByUnix");`

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/tDfdM)

Notice you can also use `asort($array);` but this will compare also the "random" field and keep the key - if this what you need then look at Mangesh answer

Comment: Ooh clever and clean, let me give it a shot

Comment: Nice of you to promote someone else's answer! But your answer is exactly what I wanted! Just out of curiosity, is there a way to flip this array using the current method without `array_reverse`? Or is it just easier to do it with that

Comment: I guess you can just change the function to `$b["unix"] - $a["unix"]` - notice the `$b` at the beginning makes it DESC. If this help you you may mark it as accepted

Comment: Oh doy, obviously - why didn't I think of that? Hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

Note:If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.

Refer : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

```
asort($array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

It will give you the output as

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [unix] => 1556547761
            [random] => 2
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [unix] => 1556547761
            [random] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [unix] => 1556547765
            [random] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [unix] => 1556547769
            [random] => 5
        )

)
```

You can keep the array key `[1],[0],[3],[2])` as it is Or you can keep it as sequential as per your requirement.